# confusion with the erlang clauses

Tags: erlang

I am very very new to erlang, and I am just learning from a book ([programming erlang](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193778553X)). I am having some doubts in these lines, which is used as a *for loop*:

lib_misc.erl:

```
for(Max, Max, F) -> [F(Max)];
for(I, Max, F) -> [F(I)|for(I+1, Max, F)].
```

And then doing so:

```
1> lib_misc:for(1,10,fun(I) -> I end).
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Will someone please explain to me what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first clause, `for(Max, Max, F)`, uses the same variable name for the first two arguments.  Therefore, this clause only matches when the first two arguments are equal.  This could also have been written like this:

```
for(I, Max, F) when I =:= Max -> ...
```

The second clause calls the provided function `F`, and then makes a recursive call to itself with the counter increased.  Eventually, this call will reach the first clause, and the "loop" terminates.

(However, this function will never terminate if `I` starts out greater than `Max`, e.g. `for(2, 1, fun integer_to_list/1)`.)

Comment: The easiest way to make it safe is to add a *guard* to the second clause `for(I, Max, F) when I < Max -> ...` which will exclude when `I` starts greater than `Max` and generate an error.